# No output for ssh host "awk '{print $0}' /path/to/log.txt"

Tags: ssh, awk

I'm trying to pull some data out of logs on remote machines using awk, and have noticed that if I ssh into the machine and run

```
awk '{print $0}' /path/to/log.txt
```

I get the expected output (containing log messages, stack traces, etc.), but if I run

```
ssh host "awk '{print $0}' /path/to/log.txt"
```

then the output looks like the following:

```
0
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: tangentially: `awk '{print $0}' file` == `cat file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the dollar sign.

```
ssh host "awk '{print \$0}' /path/to/log.txt"
```

Because the single quotes don't protect the `$0` on the local side, it gets substituted befor it's sent to the remote side.

You could also try:

```
ssh host 'awk "{print \$0}" /path/to/log.txt'
```

That protects the `$0` on the remote side, but it takes more changes to your command.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it without backslashing :

```
ssh domain.tld <<'EOF'
awk '{print $1}' /var/log/syslog*
EOF
```

This uses *here-docs* :

```
man bash | less +/'Here Documents'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ssh host "awk '{print}' /path/to/log.txt"
```

It works because $0 is the default for print.

If you have $ in your command, it would be simpler to create the command in a script file. Then you could do:

```
ssh host < cmdfile #cmdfile contains the command
```

The single quotes do not prevent variable expansion. A script does.